# ptyhon, pydantic, convert/cast str to EmailStr

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a password form `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` (located in `fastapi/security/oauth2.py`). I'm getting a username from this form (that is email in reality). But I can't pass this username to my crud.geet_user_by_email function because the last one expecting exactly `Emailstr` type from `pydanctic`  not `str`. What I should do?

code:

```
@app.post("/token", response_model=schemas.Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
        form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
        db: Session = fastapi.Depends(database.get_db)):
    user = authenticate_user(crud.get_user_by_email(email=form_data.username, db=db),
                             form_data.username, form_data.password)
```

CRUD function

```
def get_user_by_email(db: Session, email: EmailStr):
return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == email).first()
```

Comment: You should show us your code, so we can replicate the problem.

Comment: @KlausD. Aadddedd  source code

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple: `email = EmailStr(username)`